# C# Returning Wrong Integer Value

Tags: c#, forms, methods, return, return-value

i am trying to return an index based on the input of an user, the input is 2 characters only, like, a1, b2, c3...

```
public int returnInt(string x)
        {
            if (x == "a")
                return 0;
            else if (x == "b")
                return 1;
            else if (x == "c")
                return 2;
            else if (x == "d")
                return 3;
            else if (x == "e")
                return 4;
            else if (x == "f")
                return 5;
            else if (x == "g")
                return 6;
            else if (x == "h")
                return 7;
            else if (x == "1")
                return 0;
            else if (x == "2")
                return 1;
            else if (x == "3")
                return 2;
            else if (x == "4")
                return 3;
            else if (x == "5")
                return 4;
            else if (x == "6")
                return 5;
            else if (x == "7")
                return 6;
            else if (x == "8")
                return 7;
            return 0;
        }
```

> And this is where i use the method:

```
var toMove = myButtonArray[returnInt(totxt.Text.Substring(0)), returnInt(totxt.Text.Substring(1))];
```

> the method works fine for the second substring, but it doesn't work for the first substring(0). Can anyone help me about this? When I type a1, program should return to 1 and 1 but it only returns 0 for the first substring.

Comment: Substring returns everything after the index given in the first parameter. Look up the documentation and the examples in it.

Comment: Use the 2nd overloaded version of the String.Substring function. Change to `var toMove = myButtonArray[returnInt(totxt.Text.Substring(0,1)), returnInt(totxt.Text.Substring(1,1))];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's operate with single *characters*, not *string*s:

```
public int returnInt(char x) =>
    x >= 'a' && x <= 'h' ? x - 'a'
  : x >= '1' && x <= '8' ? x - '1'
  : 0;
```

Then you can put:

```
var toMove = myButtonArray[returnInt(totxt.Text[0]), returnInt(totxt.Text[1])];
```

please, note, that we get **0th** and **1st** `char`, not `string`

Comment: thank you for solving this problem, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since your input string is always 2 characters only, and you want to use them as index for your 2-d array, you need to change your code to below:

```
var toMove = myButtonArray[returnInt(totxt.Text.Substring(0,1)), 
                           returnInt(totxt.Text.Substring(1,1))];
```

This way you are saying to String.Substring function to return 1 character at a time, and mentioning the start index as first input argument.